# How To Recover My Data From Not Detected Hard Disk?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, acer-aspire

I am using Acer Laptop one day before my Hard Disk is not detected in BIOS and not booting it's shows **Insert Boot Disk** and I am try another H.D.D it's boot perfectly in my Laptop but,I want detect and recover my data on not detected hard disk. I am not experience about Hard Disk please, can any one help me how to recover my data from not detected Hard Disk.

Comment: You need to have it detected, by some computer somewhere.  But this is a tricky area -- cables to be installed, jumpers set, etc -- so you'd best ask a knowledgeable buddy to help (and maybe supply the detecting computer).

Answer (score 3):

With the information given so far, the only answer with a high probability to work is to employ a commercial data recovery service.
If the data is *really* valuable, consider doing this.
In this case, trying to solve the problem yourself may do more harm than good.

There are many possible causes, drive's internal hardware, firmware, connector,... . Have you had a look at the Related questions on the right? For example, [How do I recover data from my presumably dead hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/365999/how-do-i-recover-data-from-my-presumably-dead-hard-disk?rq=1).

Try connecting the drive to a computer that is running a different OS. For example, boot Linux from a disc.

You might get more focused help if you stated the exact model names of both drive and computer, and told us possible reasons why the drive failed to work (impact?).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another device for recover your data. Its hard to connect to another computer that is running Windows. Note: your Hard Drive should be on **Slave** mode and the other one Hard Drive that the operating system is on it should be **Master**. Also, if your Hard Drive is not recognized in any way can not access your Data.

Comment: my hdd disk not detected i am try another computer any possible solution for recover my data?

Comment: Your H.D.D damaged and your Hard Drive has a Hardware problem. When you connect the Hard Drive to a Power Supply is turned on? Can you feel?

Comment: yes i am feel hard disk power supply!

Comment: If your hard drive is turned on but is not recognized, maybe your Hard Drive main board has a problem. Your Hard Drive main board must be repair by a professional or corporate guarantee.