# How to retrieve data from dead hard disc

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

i have a hard disc that is completely dead. dead in the sense the hard disc is not even detecting in computer or neither starting. i had data in that hard disc which is important. How can i take retrieve the data from that drive?

Comment: Unless your willing to send it to a data recovery company you don't.

Comment: if you cannot get the bios to detect the disk, then you are already past the point where standard utilities can assist you. Since we don't have any insight into why the drive is offline, we can't make any good recommendations. some folks have luck replacing the disk controller card integrated into the disk, but that is dangerous and may not get you anywhere at all.

Comment: That's why backups are so important. You just estimate how important the data is and if you're willing to pay quite solid money for data recovery to some company which specializes in that, like Ramhound said

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Recover My Data From Not Detected Hard Disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/478818/how-to-recover-my-data-from-not-detected-hard-disk), [How do I recover data from my presumably dead hard disk](http://superuser.com/questions/365999/how-do-i-recover-data-from-my-presumably-dead-hard-disk)

Answer (score -1):

Offsite back ups +10

I have successfully gotten data off drives that sounded like a coffee grinder by putting them in the freezer for 24 hours then access them quickly. depends on how much damage was done to the drive you also lessen the chances those super expensive recovery services can get data off the drive.

Did I mention go signup for an offsite backup service...

Comment: "dead in the sense the hard disc is not even detecting in computer or neither starting" - putting it in a freezer is not going to solve this...