# Hard drive trouble trying to recover data

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hard-drive-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I recover data from my presumably dead hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/365999/how-do-i-recover-data-from-my-presumably-dead-hard-disk)

How to get my information off my old hard drive to my new one

So I wanna know can anyone help me

1. Laptop stop working and have me a hard disk error
2. I finally got it to boot up again after playing with it, and I tried to copy my stuff and it froze on me and hasn't booted since
3. Bought another hard drive and ended up making an image of my friends computer but couldn't get my stuff off my old drive
4. so I tried the freezer method now and I put it in for two hours and it didn't boot but I'm putting it back in for 12hrs
5. So my end result is I just wanna get my drive up enough to create an image of my CPU to my new hard drive and is there another way I could do it if my hard drive won't boot!!

   But here's the kickers when I made the image of my friends computerized up loaded it to the new hard drive and I have my old hard drive plugged up to an USB enclosure so I need help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Quite often a hard drive that won't boot can still have the data pulled off of it by mounting it on another running system.

Since you already pulled the drive from the machine to freeze it, this should be relatively easy.

take the drive and hook it up to a desktop or alternatively an adapter made for such things.  I use an external adapter quite often to do this quite often.

Once your drive is hooked up, browse to the drive on the working machine and look for your data there!

Answer (score -1):

(4.) <strike>Don't freeze your hdd, it's completely useless, even worse</strike>Try to freeze your hdd as the last attempt to recover, it may damage your hdd, by condensation of water inside hdd, after getting out of freezer. Unfreeze by degrees to prevent damaging and do not use that hdd until it gets to standard tepreature.

(5.) I recommend, not using that hdd, if there are some important data on it, find professional data recovery help.

Comment: Freezing the hard drive is not useless - there are many reported cases where the hard drive is usable after freezing but you must put it in a freezer bag to prevent moisture from getting in - http://geeksaresexy.blogspot.com/2006/01/freeze-your-hard-drive-to-recover-data.html

Comment: I have personal experience with freezing failing drives as a last resort (*obviously* with adequate moisture protection using multiple zip-lock bags), and even though I was extremely sceptical the first time, it *does* work (YMMV) to get them running for those precious extra few minutes so that you can pull more data off (can be repeated until they die completely).